Generation of default appsettings.json when implementing dependency injection in BackgroundService, .NET 6
I wrote an application which main purpose is collecting data by OPC UA protocol. I use IHosting extension method UseWindowsService when building the host.
As this was my first project where I tried dependency injection, I created logging class for writing info to txt files on target system. I also use an appsettings.json file for application settings:
IHost host = Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
  .UseWindowsService()
  .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) => {
    services.AddSingleton<IOpcLogger, OpcFileLogger>(provider => new OpcFileLogger(@$"{System.AppContext.BaseDirectory}\logs"));
    services.AddSingleton(hostContext.Configuration.GetSection("OpcSettings").Get<OpcSettings>()!);
    services.AddHostedService<OpcUaWorker>();
  })
  .Build();

It works well, but I wanted to implement default settings file creation for situation in which that file is accidentally deleted.
In my worker class I added these lines:
public OpcUaWorker(IOpcLogger opcLogger, OpcSettings opcSettings) 
{
    _opcLogger = opcLogger;
    _opcSettings = opcSettings;
} 

protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
{
    if (_opcSettings == null) 
    {
        if (!File.Exists(AppSettingsFilePath))  
        {
            JsonSerializerOptions options = new() { WriteIndented = true }; 
            using FileStream fileStream = new(AppSettingsFilePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
                await JsonSerializer.SerializeAsync<OpcSettingsWrapper>(fileStream, new OpcSettingsWrapper(new OpcSettings()), options);
        }
    }
}

If I delete appsettings.json before the service starts, either by running sc start or using the ServiceManager UI, it fails to start with an error

Service Control Manager Event 7000, The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion.

Singleton object is created once and injected using constructor, so its behavior is predictable in the example described above (after successful start deletion of the file and further check in ExecuteAsync have no sense). How to create it on start?

Did you mean BackgroundService perhaps? BackgroundWorker is an obsolete component used to perform background operations in desktop apps. It was fully replaced by async/await, Task.Run and IProgress<T> in 2012

@PanagiotisKanavos you are right

default settings file creation for situation in which that file is accidentaly deleted. what do you mean by that? The Configuration middleware doesn't require appsettings.json, they're just one source of settings. You can even use an in-memory Dictionary as a source. If you have enough information to rebuild the file, why not use that information as a source? The default Host uses settings files, environment variables and the command line as sources. Newer sources override previous ones, so you can add eg extra files to override settings

On top of that, repairing deleted files is the job of the application's installer and the OS. If you install your service using an MSI/MSIX package, the OS itself will repair any accidentally deleted files. Perhaps a better option is to put production settings in appsettings.Production.json and not delete appsettings.json for any reason (remove Delete permissions, make it readable etc).

Suppose service is stopped. Than those appsetting.json is deleted. Service want start. I mean that case. Why file? It's more convenient to conigure than command line args for now.

Is it posssible to create installer using VSCode? At the moment I use it instead of VisualStudio with the feature of MSI installers, because my  machine doesn't support it.

The service doesn't crash because appsettings.json is missing. That file is optional. It crashes because the settings are missing, so when the service tries to get eg a connection string, it gets a null and probably throws a NullReferenceException. Creating a new empty JSON file won't fix the problem, you need to find the missing settings somewhere. Why was appsettings deleted in the first place? And what do you expect the application to do if it's missing? You can specify extra settings as a dictionary or arguments if you need to

If the service depends on those settings, you shouldn't even start the service if the file is missing. Use if (!File.Exists("appsettings.json")) return -1; before calling CreateDefaultBuilder, possibly writing something to the console or Console.Error.

@PanagiotisKanavos First of all, I need to use explicit entry point and return from it. And what about using my custom logger? Dependency container injects it into service, but how to use logger before BackgroundService is created?

That problem is called Bootstrap logging - How do you log errors when the logger isn't up yet? The answer is you need a separate logger for this. Serilog uses a simpler logger with fewer sinks that gets replaced once the host is up. Windows services are a bit different though. The service process isn't OpcUaWorker but the executable itself. As far as Windows is concerned, the service starts when the process starts and responds to the service start command, not when OpcUaWorker starts

UseWindowsService already configured the process to log to the event log. Check the Application and System event logs for any events. All the classes use the ILogger middleware, not your OpcFileLogger service. To log everything to a file you need to specify a new logger to the built-in logging middleware. You can write your own but it's usually easier to use a package like Serilog.Extensions.Hosting

@PanagiotisKanavos I agree with your last notion
